# getJSON within getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, html

I have had a search but not finding anything that is helping me solve my little issue. It would be nice if I was throwing some kind of error but the following code executes partially perfectly.

In essense, I have a list of train departure at a station (returned in JSON format by a custom API departures.php), but as I am looping through this returned array, I want to call a second custom API which brings up details of the service (based on a variable pulled from the first API which is the unique identifier) using service.php.

Here is an example of the service unique ID

Y5G8DkxFcxw7+xmbbBNM1g==

However the second getJSON returns nothing at all.. its as though it doesn't exist.. though the php API functionality perfectly if used on its own

Here is the code, any pointers greatly appreciated. PLease note I have stripped out a lot of the HTML that generates the view from departure.php returned data and just left the bare basics in.

NOTE : this is purely an experiment, and not a commercial product.

```
var $crs = GetURLParameter('crs');

$.getJSON('departures.php?crs='+$crs, function (data) {

    var headertemplate = '<div class="col-md-6"><h2>Departure from ' + data.GetStationBoardResult.locationName + '</h2></div>';

    var date = new Date(data.GetStationBoardResult.generatedAt);

    var dateString = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + '-' + ("0" + date.getDate()).substr(-2);
    var timeString = ("0" + date.getHours()).substr(-2) + ':' + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);

    headertemplate += '<div class="col-md-6 text-right"><h2>Last updated: ' + timeString + ' </h2></div>';

    $("#headerArea").html(headertemplate);


    var template = '<table class="table">';
    template += '<tbody>';

    for (var i in data.GetStationBoardResult.trainServices.service) {

        template += '<tr>';
        template += '<td colspan="4">Calling at ';

        $service = data.GetStationBoardResult.trainServices.service[i].serviceID;

        $.getJSON('servicedetails.php?service='+$service, function (data2) {
            for (var j in data2.GetServiceDetailsResult.subsequentCallingPoints.callingPointList.callingPoint) {
                template += data2.GetServiceDetailsResult.subsequentCallingPoints.callingPointList.callingPoint[j].locationName;
                template += ', ';
            }
        });
    template += '</tr>';

    }

    template += '</tbody>';
    template += '</table>';

    $("#dataArea").html(template);

});
```

Just to follow this through, the URL sends a three letter string which is used to pull off the station departure which is an array.

The script generates the station information and returns into the div with id header.

The script then loops through all the departures, building up the template which it then injects into the div with id dataArea.

In each departure, the script pulls off the details of each service to list where the train will be calling at - THIS is the bit that is totally ignored.

Comment: Are you aware how asynchronous calls (which `$.getJSON` is) work?

Comment: Are you inspected the request to servicedetails.php is made through ajax ?

Comment: I have done a bit more digging, and found that the second json IS firing (by adding a console log of the output) but it is just not amending the template with the += likely due to it being inside another function

I suspect I need to create a function for the service detail which I will then call with something like $servicedetails = getServiceDetails($service) // template += $serviceDetails

Comment: @MOLEDesign Scope is not the problem here. But as I said, you use asynchronous methods - so when you are inside the first function and building your `template`, this will not wait for the inside `$.getJSON` to finish. What probably happens is that the outher function is done, and after some seconds (when the request finishes), your inner function appends to `template` but nobody cares anymore

Comment: Thats makes sense, I adding various logging lines so I could watch the flow, and the list of departures is generated, and then I see in the log that the service details are pulled later!